# Python: formatting data from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a lot of lists of data like this:

```py
['Pardubický kraj', 'Pardubice', 'Libišany', 'Libišany']
['Královéhradecký kraj', 'Hradec Králové', 'Nechanice', 'Lubno u Nechanic']
['Královéhradecký kraj', 'Hradec Králové', 'Nechanice', 'Nechanice']
```

and I need create one string which will look like this:

```py
Královéhradecký kraj`
  Hradec Králové
    1 Nechanice
      1a Lubo u Nechanic
      1b Nechanice

Pardubický kraj
  Pardubice
    2 Libišany
      2a Libišany
```

In other words the last element of each list is unique but other elements that are hierarchically above may be the same and may not be repeated in case of agreement. I also need each hierarchical group to be sorted alphabetically. And I don't know how to do it.

I will be grateful for any advice

Thanks

Edit:

if I give some more example:

```py
['black', 'one', 'cat']
['black', 'two', 'dog']
['red', 'five', 'pig']
['pink', 'one', 'snake']

black
 1 one
  1a cat
 2 two
  2a dog

red
 3 five
  3a pig

pink
 4 one
  4a snake
```

Comment: what do you mean by 2a and 2b??

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far, and what was wrong with your attempt(s)? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: 2a and 2b is a type of numbering, the third element is numbered with a regular number and alphabetic letters must be added to the fourth element to distinguish it

Comment: I added another example to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a more elegant way to write this. I haven't found time to get this. So here's a quick and dirty version that still does the trick for you.

```
x = [['black', 'sugar', 'second', 'dog'],
     ['red', 'cane', 'five', 'pig'],
     ['black', 'sugar', 'first', 'cat'],
     ['pink', 'cute', 'one', 'snake'],
     ['pink', 'angry', 'one', 'donkey'],
     ['black', 'sugar', 'third', 'bird'],
     ['red', 'cane', 'five', 'monkey'],
     ['pink', 'angry', 'one', 'spider']]

x.sort()

print (x[0][0])
print ('  ' + x[0][1])
print ('   1 ' + x[0][2])
print ('     1a '+x[0][3])

level_2 = 1
level_3 = 'a'

for i,a in enumerate(x[1:]):
    if a[0] == x[i][0]:
        if a[1] == x[i][1]:
            if a[2] == x[i][2]:
                level_3 = chr(ord(level_3) + 1)
            else:
                level_2 +=1
                level_3 = 'a'
                print ('   ' + str(level_2) + ' ' + a[2])
        else:
            level_2 +=1
            level_3 = 'a'
            print ('  ' + a[1])
            print ('   ' + str(level_2) + ' ' + a[2])
    else:
        level_2 +=1
        level_3 = 'a'
        print (a[0])
        print ('  ' + a[1])
        print ('   ' + str(level_2) + ' ' + a[2])
    print ('     ' + str(level_2) + level_3 + ' ' + a[3])
```

The output of this is:

```
black
  sugar
   1 first
     1a cat
   2 second
     2a dog
   3 third
     3a bird
pink
  angry
   4 one
     4a donkey
     4b spider
  cute
   5 one
     5a snake
red
  cane
   6 five
     6a monkey
     6b pig
```